# performance problems on an 8 Cores VPS with 6 GB RAM...Shall I buy the Litespeed webserver?

Tags: performance

I have this VPS:

```
RAM: 6144 MB
CPU: 8 Cores
SSD hard disk
```

I have the following Magento accounts on my VPS server:

```
1. Magento ver. 1.9.1.0 with php 5.5
2. Magento ver. 2.1.0 with php 5.6
3. another installation of Magento - ver. 1.9.1.0 with php 5.6
```

The server often has a load of 5 or 6 and the websites run slow.

My hosting provides says this:

"The load 5-6 is normal in your case. Its quite busy VM, however you have 6 cores, and anything bellow 6 load points will not affect performance.

Replacing PHP-CGI/Apache with litespeed webserver will reduce the load though. Anyway, things looks normal with load consideration heavy PHP traffic. Are you have any slow downs? Should be any with this load. Consider LSWS webserver."

What do you think? **Shall I actually get the Litespeed webserver? It would cost me an extra $20/month. Would it increase the perfomance considerably?** I tried upgrading the 1.9.1 to 1.9.2.4 but it was not successful...

Comment: you have cPanel server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, it would not increase the performance considerably. Also, you can configure Nginx as reverse proxy, and gets most benefits of Litespeed server for free.

Best way, to improve performance in your case is use Varnish FPC (if you still do not use it) and migrate to php 7.

Comment: Would php 7 work with Magento 1.9.1.0 also? How much is Varnish FPC?

Comment: @Allysin for 1.9.1.0 you will need the Inchoo PHP7 module

Comment: @Allysin, price start from zero - https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/turpentine-varnish-cache.html. But you should  choose which best for you